# How to use glmnet with panel data?

Tags: panel-data, regularization, glmnet

I would like to use regularization from the package glmnet on my panel data. I have the following data: country - year - gdp - population - water usage, so for each country, I have a year in which the GDP is measured and the population. Now what I want to do is something like:

$$Pop_{c,t}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}GDP_{c,t} + \beta_{2}Water_{c,t}$$

Now I know this is a nonsense model, but I am still practising, so please show me mercy. The question is how can I apply a fixed effects model or something with regularization in R?

How do people generally model this?

Are there any good papers / books that explain how I should do this?

My last question, if I just do something trivial like this:

$$Pop_{c,t}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}GDP2001_{c} + \beta_{2} GDP2002_{c} + \beta_{3}Water2001_{c} + \beta_{4}Water2002_{c}$$

Does it have any negative effects? Is there a paper that explains what the consequences are if I do this?

Thanks!